# How can the cause of unexpected end of JSON input be isolated

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have a Python program that is attempting to post a dictionary read from a file to a URL.  The dictionary is as follows:

```
    {
     "location": "loc",
     "host": "host.somewhere.com",
     "body": "Test Notification from host",
     "attributes": {
          "short_description": "host - This is a test",
          "definition": "some.program generated a(n) alert",
          "condition": "host called notify alert.",
          "create_time": "1605721114",
          "event_class": "event.class.some.program:alert:info",
          "reporter_severity": 9,
          "reporter_name": "some.program.info",
          "alert_type": "create",
          "action_uri": ""
     }
}
```

The post code is as follows:

```
# Read the file from disk.
with open(lNotification, "r") as jsonFile:
    lNotificationDict = json.load(jsonFile)
    lNotificationData = jsonFile.read()

.
.
.
# Send the request.
lHeaders = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
lResp = requests.post(
        lConfigParms['SendToURL'],
        headers=lHeaders,
        data=lNotificationData
)
```

I am getting the error below:

{"status":400,"message":"Error when processing the alert: unexpected end of JSON input"}

I have taken the content of the JSON file and used curl to post the request and it succeeds.  Also, I have used a couple different tools to validate the JSON.  All the tools used report that the JSON is valid.

Any suggestions as to isolate the cause of the error?

Comment: Have you tried changing `data=lNotificationData` to `json=lNotificationData`?

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to inspect what is being sent/received when you perform the request from python.

Comment: You are reading the same file twice, in `json.load(jsonFile)` and `jsonFile.read()`. After the first read, you are looking at the end of the file and read nothing in the second one.

Comment: OK, duh!  Been looking at it too long!  Thank you for pointing out the obvious.